# HTML 5 - add Shape on mouseover

Tags: html, mouseover, kineticjs, shapes

I use KineticJS to create shape and animate them.

I have a triangle :

```
var triangle1Over = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [120, 10, 225, 140, 15, 140, 120, 10],
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
```

I would like to make it appears **one time** on mouseover event.

```
triangle1.on('mouseover', function () {
    layer.add(triangle1Over);
    layer.draw();
});
```

**The issue :** on every cursor move in triangle1, the shape triangle1Over is added > this is bad because it's blinking.

I try to find something: "if the shape hasn't already been added to the layer, add it". But nothing.

Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the colors of the triangle on mouseenter and on mouseleave?

That would eliminate any “flicker” that’s causes when your 2 triangles overlap:

```
triangle1.on('mouseenter', function () {
console.log("over");
    triangle1.setStroke("orange");
    triangle1.setFill("green");
    layer.draw();
});


triangle1.on('mouseleave', function() {
    triangle1.setStroke("red");
    triangle1.setFill("white");
    layer.draw();
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/35hKX/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var triangle1 = new Kinetic.Polygon({
        points: [120, 10, 225, 140, 15, 140, 120, 10],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fill:"white"

    });
    layer.add(triangle1);
    layer.draw();


    triangle1.on('mouseenter', function () {
    console.log("over");
        triangle1.setStroke("orange");
        triangle1.setFill("green");
        layer.draw();
    });


    triangle1.on('mouseleave', function() {
        triangle1.setStroke("red");
        triangle1.setFill("white");
        layer.draw();
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as in my code, it's blinking ! When a mouseover event is handled, it will call the function on each mousemove. This is my real issue :(

Comment: I’m not really sure about the effect you’re going for…but see my edited answer for a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `triangle1Over` an ID like this:

```
var triangle1Over = new Kinetic.Polygon({
  points: [120, 10, 225, 140, 15, 140, 120, 10],
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  id: triangle1OverID
});
```

You can check if it exists in the layer like this:

```
triangle1.on('mouseover', function () {
  if(typeof stage.get('#triangle1OverID')[0] == 'undefined') {
    layer.add(triangle1Over);
    layer.draw();
  }
});
```

Or you can use a name:

```
var triangle1Over = new Kinetic.Polygon({
  points: [120, 10, 225, 140, 15, 140, 120, 10],
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  name: triangle1OverName
});
```

You can check if it exists in the layer like this:

```
triangle1.on('mouseover', function () {
  var shapes = stage.get('.triangle1OverName');
  if(shapes.length) {
    layer.add(triangle1Over);
    layer.draw();
  }
});
```

Comment: Building on sumitb.mdi's answer below, it might be better to substitute the mouseover event with mouseenter for my solution. I'll leave that to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need callback functions like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` just draw the triangle1Over when the `mouseenter` function is triggered over the triangle1 and make the triangle1Over disappear when the `mouseleave` event over the triangle1Over is fired. Maybe this link of [mouseevents](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/) might help..